# interpretation of generalized eigenvalue/vectors in spectral graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, sp.spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory, eigenvector

Let us say I have a symmetric graph adjacency matrix A, a degree matrix D, a laplacian L (D-A). I have a generalized eigenvalue equation $Av=\lambda Lv$. Does the eigenvalue/vectors produced in this way have any graph theoretic interpretations?

Comment: What is the motivation for this equation?

Comment: I would imagine that this very much depends on the null space of $L$.